# Reset DRAC/MC password on Dell BladeCentre 1855

Tags: bladecenter, drac, password-reset

I have a Dell Blade Centre 1855, and nobody knows what the root password for the DRAC/MC card in the blade chassis is (I tried root/calvin).

I do not have IP access to the DRAC/MC, nor do I have physical access to the back of the blade centre to access the DRAC/MC module. I do have serial access (and can see the login prompt in hyperterm). I do have physical access to the FRONT of the chassis (the back of the cabinet is locked and lo-and-behold the key cannot be found).

Does anyone know how to reset the password? Every piece of literature I find on the internet tells me I need to log in, or run `racadm` on the host machine (which I can't, because it's inside a blade chassis).

<sub>If someone does know how to do it with physical access to the back of the bladecentre, please post it anyway, as I'm sure I'll get access to the back of the cabinet one day)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the drac from of the back of the enclosure you will see a series of pins.
move the jumper to clear password. The pin functions are printed on the printed circuit board. Put the module back in. Now remove it and put the jumper in the normal position. Now you can log in via the serial port as root/calvin.

John Markunas
Linux System Admin
Williams College

Comment: Thanks John! As soon as I have physical access to the back of the blade I'll give this a shot (to be honest I'd completely forgotten about setting up this DRAC)

Comment: I know this is now 18 months later, but for the record, this worked perfectly once we got the DRAC out of the chassis.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There is a procedure, but the easiest thing for you to do is call Dell support about it. Even if the chassis is out of warranty, they will provide best effort support and find the procedure for you

Comment: Ugh, 90 minutes of waiting on hold and being transferred from department to department. Still, I might not have much choice...

Comment: Seriously? when I was working there nobody spent that long on hold, at least not in my geo... maybe you called the wrong number?

Comment: I'm in Australia. Last time I called their support/spare parts I end up at reception, who put me through to spare parts, who then ask for my part number, and then spend 10 minutes looking it up, told me it didn't exist,and then passes me to server support, who then passes me BACK to spare parts, she doesn't recognise me from the first time I spoke to her so puts me back to reception, they put me to PowerEdge Support who sent me back to Spare Parts. This time they remembered me, said they'd send me an email with the details, and I never heard anything. All that try and get a KVM dongle!

Comment: whoa, what's pretty bad. I was doing UK/I and Russia, and people would just get through, give me a service tag, and get whatever information or troubleshooting they required.
Are you still on hold?

Comment: @dyasny, nah I was in bed. On my way to work now, but probably won't get a chance to call them today.

Comment: sorry, I've left that job a long time ago man, so I can't be of much help. good luck with the support though

Comment: btw, I love that term "best effort" - I remember it from back in my Cisco days. It basically meant "No SLA, no delivery time, it will be done when it's done". It sounds so much better than it really is!

Comment: Hmm, for us it used to mean we work as usual, but don't dispatch parts, since there's no warranty.